# `crontab -e: E212: Can't open file for writing` when using gvim (works with vi)

Tags: cron, vi, gvim

As a user, I want to edit my crontab.

`crontab -e`

`gvim` is launched. It prints

```
"/tmp/crontab.IUVYhK/crontab" [New DIRECTORY]
```

I can write but as soon as I try to write the temporary file, I get this error message:

```
"crontab.IUVYhK/crontab" E212: Can't open file for writing
```

However, I have no issue when using vi as editor:

```
EDITOR=vi crontab -e
```

Is it wrong to set `gvim` as `EDITOR`? Shold I use `vi`? I do very few admin tasks on this desktop machine, so I never ran into any issue.

Comment: That's odd, can you check the permissions on that file and directory path for problems? Parent directories will need `rx` and the file some form of `w`...

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I was using gvim, not vi and it actually made a difference. Question edited.

Comment: `gvim` (the command) returns immediately doesn't it, rather than waiting for your editing session to complete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use a synchronous editor for `crontab -e`, i.e. one where the command doesn't return until the editing is complete. For example,

```
export EDITOR="gvim --nofork"
crontab -e
```

An alternative is this,

```
crontab -l > ~/.crontab
gvim ~/.crontab
# wait until editing is finished
crontab ~/.crontab
```

Comment: `EDITOR="gvim --nofork"` apparently does the trick. Anyway, for these tasks, `vi` is fine. I don't know why I chose `gvim` in the first place.